# Replace this by only one form

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

how can I replace this code, by only one Form please.

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/deconnexion" />"><input type="submit" value="Déconnexion" class="deco" /></form>
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/accueil" />"><input type="submit" value="Retour" class="deco" /></form>
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: two buttons in only one form

Comment: J'ai donné une alternative comme réponse.

Comment: @DanyCaissy please comments and answers must be in English only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible, each form will submit it's information to a single location, which is your action property in your form.

What you can do, alternatively, is manage two different cases in the same form. Your form would look like that :

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/redirection" />">
    <input id="deco" type="submit" value="Déconnexion" class="deco" />
    <input id="retour" type="submit" value="Retour" class="deco" />
    <input id="type" name="type" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

You would need Javascript (Jquery) code to assign the type of redirection in the hidden field before the form is submitted :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#deco').click(function(event) 
    {
        $('#type').val("Déconnexion");
    });

    $('#retour').click(function(event) 
    {
        $('#type').val("Retour");
    });

</script>
```

Then, in the PHP, you would redirect to the page or function you wish with this condition :

```
if ($_POST["type"] == "Déconnexion")
    // Do something
else if ($_POST["type"] == "Retour"
    // Do something else
```